# Conditional PHP works in Node Template but not in Views Custom Fields

Tags: 6

This code in my node template checks a CCK field and prints some text dependent on the value:

```
<?php if ($node->field_stock[0]['view'] == 'No' ) : ?>
<div id="out-stock-my"><h2>Out of Stock</h2></div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

How can I do something similar with Views Custom Field's PHP filed type? 
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If 'm not mistaken you are trying to move this logic out of your tpl.php template file by using [views custom field](http://drupal.org/project/views_customfield).

You first need to get the name of the accessible fields with this code.

```
<?php print var_export($data, TRUE); ?>
```

Then you should be able input in the custom field something similar to this.

```
<?php if ($data->field_stock == 'No' ) : ?>
<div id="out-stock-my"><h2>Out of Stock</h2></div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

There is more info here http://drupal.org/node/467190.

Answer (score 1):

in templates of views you can seek/use the id of the node (nid).

for example, in this case I will use views-view-unformatted.tpl.php

```
<?php
$nodeIdItem = $view->result[$id]->nid; //get the id of the current item, in this case using $view->result inside the view results loop. 
$node = node_load($nodeIdItem);
?>    
<?php if ($node->field_stock[0]['view'] == 'No' ) : ?>
<div id="out-stock-my"><h2>Out of Stock</h2></div>
<?php endif; ?>
```